# How to drop unused levels in table with data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the following `data.table`:

```
x <- data.table(
          x=sample(letters[1:5],10,rep=T), 
          y=factor(sample(letters[1:5],10,rep=T), levels=letters))
```

This situation arises several times while working with `data.table`s where  some of the factor fields have unused variables.

Now, if we use the following table:

```
table(x)
```

A giant table with all unused levels shows up.
Is there a way in `table` methods or `data.table` to do this?

I know that following is possible:

```
x$y <- factor(x$y)
```

But this is not useful because I don't want to save each of the sub-tables to a different variable.

Comment: I don't understand, what's wrong with just `x[, y := factor(y)]`?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `droplevel` as follows

```
x[,y:=droplevels(y)]
```

this overwrites `y` by reference with `droplevels(y)`

Results in

```
> table(x)
   y
x   b c d e
  a 1 1 1 2
  b 0 1 0 0
  c 1 0 0 0
  d 1 0 0 0
  e 0 0 2 0
```

Comment: How is different from OPs `x[, y := factor(y)]`? am I missing something here?

Comment: @ David Arenburg, i totally agree. `droplevels.factor` just does that. It calls `factor(y)`. Yes, you could also do `x[, y := factor(y)]`. This is most likely even faster. I understood the question was more about `:=` so changing it by reference.