# Dropping unused factor levels in data.table

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out the syntax for dropping unused factor levels in a data.table given a character vector of column names similar to what's done in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881887/how-to-drop-unused-levels-in-table-with-data-table). However in that example "y" is the actual column name of the data.table "x". I would like to pass instead a character vector holding the column names but I could not figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `.SDcols` to specify the columns of interest.  It can take a vector of columns names (length of 1 or greater than 1) or column index.  Now, the `.SD` i.e. Subset of Data.table would have those columns specified in the `.SDcols`.  As there is only a single column, extract that column with `[[`, apply the `droplevels` on the `vector` and assign (`:=`) it back to the column of interest.  Not the parens around the object identifier v1.  It is to evaluate the object to get the value in it instead of creating a column 'v1'

```
x[, (v1) := droplevels(.SD[[1]]), .SDcols = v1]
```

Usually, the syntax would be

```
x[, (v1) := lapply(.SD, droplevels), .SDcols = v1]
```

It can take one column or multiple columns. The only reason to extract (`[[`) is because we know it is a single column

Another option is `get`

```
x[, (v1) :=  droplevels(get(v1))]
```

where,

```
v1 <- "y"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the [[1]] is doing?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I removed the [[1]] in the first solution and the columns referenced by v1 became filled with <NA>, what's the reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: @Yandle Not able to reproduce the issue for me `x[, (v1) := droplevels(.SD), .SDcols = v1]; levels(x$y)#
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"`

Comment: `droplevels` work on data.frame or vector, but some functions wouldn't work in that way.  Can you try by creating the example data again

Comment: It appears I was using factors instead of droplevels, which gives identical results when [[1]] is included but fills the referenced column with <NA>s when the [[1]] is removed

Comment: @Yandle As I mentioned, each function have a particular behavior, `factor` works on `vector` rather than on a data.frame or data.table

Comment: @Yandle Based on `?factor` `x - a vector of data, usually taking a small number of distinct values.`

Comment: @Yandle If you do `factor(list(c("A", "B")))#
[1] c("A", "B")
Levels: c("A", "B")` and that value is not there creating `NA` values, similar to `x[, (v1) := factor(.SD), .SDcols = v1]`

Answer (score 1):

@akrun's answer works well, i think this works too

`x[, (v1):=droplevels(x[[v1]])]`