# An alternative to mutate_if in data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I've been using heavily the tidyverse, but for some projects I need the speed of data.table. So far I understand most of the DT syntax, but I want to drop unused levels in data.table without using `mutate_if`.

With `dplyr` I can use `mutate_if(dataframe, is.factor, droplevels)` and that's it. However, I can't find a way around with data.table.

I've tried to apply [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881887/how-to-drop-unused-levels-in-table-with-data-table) using `dataframe[, (.SD) := droplevels(.SD), .SDcols = sapply(dataframe, is.factor)]`

It throws the following error: `Error in`[.data.table`(DT_, ,`:=`((.SD), droplevels(.SD)), .SDcols = sapply(DT_,  : 
  LHS of := isn't column names ('character') or positions ('integer' or 'numeric')`.

I expect to have the same result as in `mutate_if` without using the tidyverse.

**UPDATE**

I accepted [G. Grothendieck's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516548/g-grothendieck) answer because the code was more like I was expecting.

The example he used was this:

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a = 1:5, 
                 b = factor(1:5, levels = 1:10), 
                 c = factor(6:10, levels = 1:10))
```

The data I used for this example was the following:

```r
set.seed(42)
DT1 = data.table(
  A = LETTERS[1:10],
  B = c(1:10),
  C = factor(sample(LETTERS, 10), levels = LETTERS),
  D = factor(sample(LETTERS, 10), levels = LETTERS)
)
```

The columns of interest are:

```
> DT1[, C]
 [1] Q E A J D R Z O G V
Levels: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
> DT1[, D]
 [1] Y E N T R O C I D Z
Levels: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

And the results are

```r
# with base
DT1 = droplevels(DT1)

# or by reference
DT1[, (names(DT1)) := droplevels(.SD)]
```

With the following output:

```
> DT1[, C]
 [1] Q E A J D R Z O G V
Levels: A D E G J O Q R V Z
> DT1[, D]
 [1] Y E N T R O C I D Z
Levels: C D E I N O R T Y Z
```

Thanks everyone for your answers, that was quick!

Comment: Take a look at [`table.express`](https://asardaes.github.io/table.express/articles/table.express.html#modifying-subset-of-data), there's an equivalent of `mutate_if` (shown in the examples there).

Comment: Could you show an example of your data as well as your expected outcome?

Comment: BTW, this is probably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56502574/5793905), but that one isn't accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the data in the Note at the end

```
DT[, (names(DT)) := droplevels(.SD)]
```

or

```
DT <- droplevels(DT)
```

Check:

```
levels(DT$b)
## [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"

levels(DT$c)
## [1] "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
```

If `droplevels` in the question is just an example and the real function you are using does not have a data.frame method then use code corresponding to this:

```
wx <- which(sapply(DT, is.factor))
DT[, (wx) := lapply(.SD, droplevels), .SDcols = wx]
```

### Note

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a = 1:5, 
                 b = factor(1:5, levels = 1:10), 
                 c = factor(6:10, levels = 1:10))
```

### Update

Simplified.

Answer (score 6):

Not a `data.table` solution, but this can be done neatly with base R's `rapply`:

```r
## data
data("iris")
## add dummy level
levels(iris$Species) <- c(levels(iris$Species), "dummy")
str(iris)
#> 'data.frame':    150 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#>  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#>  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#>  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#>  $ Species     : Factor w/ 4 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

iris2 <- rapply(iris, f = droplevels, classes = "factor", how = "replace")
str(iris2)
#> 'data.frame':    150 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#>  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#>  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#>  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#>  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `set()`

Input data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(iris)
DT[, Species := as.factor(Species)]
DT <- DT[Species == "setosa"]

DT[, levels(Species)]
#[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

Get the column names that are factors and replace by reference

```
cols <- DT[, names(Filter(is.factor, .SD))]
for(j in cols) {
  set(DT, j = j, value = droplevels(DT[[j]]))
}
# could also be written as a one-liner - thanks to @MattSummersgill
# for(j in cols) set(DT, j = j, value = droplevels(DT[[j]]))
```

Giving

```
DT[, levels(Species)]
#[1] "setosa"
```

Comment: I use `data.table::set()` this way as well. For what it's worth, I prefer to do the loop all on a single line if it's less than ~80 characters. i.e.  `for(j in cols) set(DT, j = j, value = droplevels(DT[[j]]))`

Answer (score 2):

To add to my comment,
you can give [`table.express`](https://asardaes.github.io/table.express/articles/table.express.html) a try,
although the examples should be updated because they can be simplified.
Here's one example equivalent to `mutate_if`:

```
library(data.table)
library(table.express)

data("iris")

DT <- as.data.table(iris)

DT %>%
  start_expr %>%
  mutate(Species = as.factor(Species)) %>%
  mutate_sd(is.factor(.COL), droplevels) %>%
  end_expr
```

Check the whole vignette though,
some verbs are eager and some are lazy.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
x <- data.table(
  x=sample(letters[1:5],10,rep=T), 
  y=factor(sample(letters[1:5],10,rep=T), levels=letters),
  w=factor(sample(letters[1:5],10,rep=T), levels=letters)
  )
factors <- colnames(x)[sapply(x, is.factor)]
lapply(factors, function(z) x[, eval(z):=droplevels(get(z))])
```